# react-hook-form custom resolver extend default one

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a custom resolver that contains async validation checks for multiple fields. My checks work, but the problem is that the default rules are ignored. How can I extend the default resolver with my own custom additions?

In the documentation it says `A resolver cannot be used with the built-in validators (e.g.: required, min, etc.)`. What should I do then?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? You're correct, you can't use the field level validation rules like `required`, `min` , etc. You need to refactor your form to include these rules inside your validation schema

Answer (score 0):

Use third party validators with resolver. I use [Joi](https://joi.dev/) now, previously [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup), but there are others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).